# snap-store can't write to /run/user/0

Tags: permissions

I just tried to check why the snap-store wasn't updating & I got these 2 messages:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
17:41:04:0749 GLib-GIO g_app_info_get_name: assertion 'G_IS_APP_INFO (appinfo)' failed
```

I checked the directory & /run/user/0 didn't exist.  I created it to continue, but the 2nd message still appears.  First, this is Ubuntu 22.04, why wouldn't the /run/user/0 directory exist?  Second, what does this other message mean?

Comment: The complete input you used --and the complete output too-- would be great additions to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've had to reboot & don't have the output of the command anymore.